# hg largefile XXX missing from store (needs to be uploaded)

Tags: mercurial

A coworker got this error after pulling from the repo. I searched for an answer online on how to solve it but couldn't find anything. I figured out a way to solve it so posting it below for anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked everyone else working on the repository to check their user cache folder (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\largefiles on Windows) to see if they had a file with that id ("XXX" from the title).

One of them did, the original author of the file.

I asked him to send it to me, I remote connected to the server that has the central repo. I then copied the file both to the server's cache and into .hg\largefiles

The user could then pull again and push and everything worked.

Comment: The basic idea with largefiles is that you cannot push revision `R` without also uploading the largefiles referenced in `R` (and ancestor changesets). So it is strange that the `XXX` file was missing in your central repository. I suggest you open a bug here and add all the info you have: http://bz.selenic.com/

Answer (score 0):

LF extension seems not compatible with keyword extension. 
With these both extensions, at the commit, the LF is NOT put in the configured folder on the PC and then raises this error at push.
If you disable the keyword extension, it's perfectly working.
Unfortunately, I've not found any additional explanations.
If someone could provide a stable solution, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `hg pull` is happily sparse, but `hg push` is not; thus you need all largefiles for every revision not already present on the new remote, so that it can populate for history and allow clients to successfully pull at any revision.  Which makes sense.

When migrating to a new hg server, I hit this issue.  The "within Mercurial" solution was to download *all* largefiles, for all commits, to my local repo, and then push to the new server repo:

```
$ hg lfpull --rev 1-tip
$ hg push newbox
```

*(Disclaimer: my Mercurial-fu is weak, I only use it for this one largefile repo)*